# Biostatistics book suggestion

Tags: references, biostatistics, sas, clinical-trials

I am a statistical programmer and am working on SAS in a pharma company.
Also I have masters in statistics and have interest in the subject.

Can anyone suggest me books on biostatistics, helps in SAS writing and stuff. I wish to move to biostatistics profile from programmer but I do not have hands on experience in designing statistical methods. It would be great if you suggest me a basic book to start with biostatistics.?

Comment: Does one of [our threads tagged both "references" and "biostatistics"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biostatistics%2breferences) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert R. Sokal and F. James Rolf, *Introduction to Biostatistics*, W. H. Freeman and Co., San Francisco. 1973.  368pp

A second edition is available as a Dover reprint of the 1987 impression. For the assiduous student, the book is indispensable. Electronic availability is noted below.

Also by the same authors -

*Biometry: The Principles and Practices of Statistics in Biological Research*,
also published by W. H. Freeman as a new impression in 1995.  899pp. This is also an evidently indispensable and comprehensive text.

Please note, both of these books are available electronically from z-library at [this link](https://b-ok.cc/).  Simply search on the authors' names to bring up the electronically available texts.